# HTML CSS DIVs arrangement

Tags: css, html

[image: Mock website design]

Hi all. I need help in arrange the div of my website.
My website has 3 main DIVs.
 1. DIV1 - My Header (fixed height)
 2. DIV2 - Dynamic Content area so height varies
 3. DIV3 - My Footer (fixed height)

All DIVs have 100% width.

The DIV1 header must have 0px with respect to the top of the browser. I wanted the 3 DIVs must be on top of each other as shown in the image. If the user has a resolution taller than my 3 DIVs, what will be at the most bottom after the DIVs are just empty spaces. However, I cant seem to get that layout working. the DIV3 footer keep giving me trouble.

I've following CSS code:

```
div1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}
div2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
}
div3 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}
```

If I use `position: fixed` for DIV3, and my DIV2 has a shorter content, the whole website will look weird.
If I try changed to position: relative for DIV3, DIV3 will overlap and appear in front of DIV1.

Is there any better suggestion for that?
Thank you very much.

Comment: If you want to learn Positioning kindly check http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/ Nice stuff

Comment: The problem is that you are making `div`s 1 and 3 `fixed` and then positioning them at the top of the screen so that one is on top of the other. Given the CSS you've shown, `div` 3 will be on top of `div` 1.

Answer (score 0):

Check this: [CSS layout generator.](http://csslayoutgenerator.com/)

**EDIT:**
Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GN5X2/8/)

Try using:

```
.head{
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
}
.footer{
  position:fixed; 
  bottom:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you're using positioning to layout the div's?

Div's will naturally stack on top of each other without any need for positioning.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want fixed header and footer positioning.

http://www.cssplay.co.uk/layouts/basics2.html

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="div1">header</div>
<div class="div2">Content area</div>
<div class="div3">Footer</div>
```

CSS

```
.div1 {
height:100px; background:red; width:100%
}
.div2 {
position: relative;
top: 0px; background:green; width:100%; height:100px;
}
.div3 {
 background:blue; width:100%; height:100px;
}​
```

​Demo http://jsfiddle.net/K3Unz/2/

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may be helpful to you
 use footer as `bottom: 0px;` if you want to fixed this in bottom

Here the demo: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FCwjc/37/)

```
body{
background:green;
}

div.one {
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
background: #4f4f4f;
}
div.two {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
margin-top: 50px;
}
 div.three {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
background: red;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In style, I put same height for div1,div2,div3 = 100px :

```
<style>
body
{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#div1 {
    height: 100px;
    width:100%;
    top: 0px;
    background-color:#F00;
}
#div2 {
    height: 100px;
    width:100%;
    top: 0px;
    background-color:#00F;
}
#div3 {
    height: 100px;
    width:100%;
    top: 0px;
    background-color:#FF0;
}
</style>
```

and in html tags:

```
<body>
    <div id="div1">Header</div>
    <div id="div2">Cotent</div>
    <div id="div3">Footer</div>
</body>
```

I hope this will fit your requirements,